# Word for "Fear of not living up to one's potential"

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

There are lot of different phobias out there, but I'm unable to find the one that relates to a "fear of not living up to ones potential".

Comment: Why do you assume such a fear exists (or that there is a word for it)? What similar fears have you already looked up but rejected?

Comment: Is this a fear or a phobia? A phobia is a mental illness, not just an emotional response.

Answer (score 1):

The only word I could find is; Atychiphobia - fear of failure. [Phobia list](https://massivephobia.com/phobia-list-fear-of-phobias/). That would seems similar to a 'fear of success', [Jonah Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_complex). *"The Jonah complex is the fear of success which prevents self-actualization, or the realization of one's potential. It is the fear of one's own greatness, the evasion of one's destiny, or the avoidance of exercising one's talents."*